# EXTjs 3.4.0 render a ID field in grid with NAME

Tags: javascript, extjs3

I have a EXTjs grid, which displays some fields from my custome tables in database..

```
Reports.grid.Reports = function(config) {
    config = config || {};
    Ext.applyIf(config,{
        id: 'reports-grid-reports'
        ,url: Reports.config.connectorUrl
        ,baseParams: { action: 'mgr/reports/getList' }
        ,save_action: 'mgr/reports/updateFromGrid'
        ,fields: ['id','name','filename','remark','year','resourceID','typeID','visible']
```

and then :

```
{
             header: 'Type ID'
            ,dataIndex: 'typeID'
            ,sortable: true
            ,width: 100

         }
```

My types table has typeid and name.. my grid displays the number, How can I tell it to display the coresponding name for that id in the table instead?

I also got a combobox which I use in update window:

```
Reports.combo.Types = function(config) {
    config = config || {};
    Ext.applyIf(config,{          
         name: 'typeID'       
        ,hiddenName: 'typeID'
        ,displayField: 'name'
        ,valueField: 'id'
        ,fields: ['name','id']
        ,listWidth: 380       
        ,pageSize: 20
        ,url: Reports.config.connectorUrl
        ,baseParams: {
                action: 'mgr/reports/gettypelist2', 'combo': true
            }           
    });
    Reports.combo.Types.superclass.constructor.call(this,config);
};
Ext.extend(Reports.combo.Types,MODx.combo.ComboBox);
Ext.reg('combo-modx-types',Reports.combo.Types);
```

Using ,displayField: 'name' makes combo display name instead of the id.. how can I do the same thing in grid?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, I believe you would need to customise the getList processor rather than in the ExtJS directly. Override the afterIteration() function. Something along the lines of:

```
public function afterIteration(array $list) {
    $rows = array();
    foreach ($list as $row){
        // This calls a custom getName() function that gets the name from the other table 
        $row['typeID'] = $this->getName($row['id']); 
        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    return $rows;
}
```

and maybe your getName() function could be something like:

```
private function getName($id) {
    $otherTable = $this->modx->getObject('TABLE_ALIAS_HERE', array('internalKey' => $id));
    $name = $otherTable->get('name');
    return $name;
}
```